# C++ operator overloading in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `matrix` and I try to override the `+` operation for different matrix. I want to override the operator in  a derived class but have a few errors. In other words, I want to be able to do only `A+B` for 2 defined objects of `matrix` and not to to do a `for` loop.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class matrix
{
    protected:
    T **tab;
    int row,col;
    public:
    matrix(int row,int col)
    {
        this->row = row;
        this->col = col;
        tab = new T* [col];
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        tab[i] = new T[row];
        tab[0][0] = 100;
    }
    T& operator()(int i,int j) 
    {
        return tab[i][j];
    }

    T operator()(int i,int j)const 
    {
        return tab[i][j];
    }
    void operator=(const matrix& that)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < col ; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < row ; j++)
            tab[i][j] = that.tab[i][j];
    }

    matrix(const T& tab)
    {
        row = tab.row;
        col = tab.col;
        tab = new T* [col];
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        tab[i] = new T[row];
    }
    ~matrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        delete tab[i];
        delete tab;
    }
};
template<class T>
class Operations: public matrix<T>
{
    T& operator+(matrix& tab1,matrix& tab2)
    {

        int i,j;
        ligne = tab.ligne;
        col = tab.col;
        tab3 = new T* [col];
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        tab3[i] = new T[ligne];

        for(i  = 0; i < col; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < ligne; j++)
            tab3[i][j] = tab1[i][j]+tab2[i][j];
        return tab3;
    }
};
int main()
{
    matrix<int> tab1(10,10);
    matrix<int> tab2(5,5);
    cout<<tab1(0,0)<<endl;
    tab1(0,0) = 10;
    cout<<tab2(0,0)<<endl;
    tab2(0,0) = 5;
    tab2 = tab1;

    tab1(0,0) = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

The class `matrix` works fine. It is when I added the `Operations` class that I got the following erros:

```
    v2.cpp:65:15: error: declaration of ‘operator+’ as non-function
  T& operator+(matrix& tab1,matrix& tab2)
               ^
v2.cpp:65:13: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
  T& operator+(matrix& tab1,matrix& tab2)
             ^
v2.cpp:65:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
  T& operator+(matrix& tab1,matrix& tab2)
```

Can you please explain me the reason for those errors and how to correct them?
Thank you

**EDIT**
I'd like to implement the + operator as a member class function in the `matrix`, but I am  getting an error message: Can you please tell me what is going wrong with the way I define operator+?

```
matrix operator+(const matrix& that)const 
    {

        int i,j;
        T** tab3;
        tab3 = new T* [col];
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        tab3[i] = new T[row];

        for(i  = 0; i < col; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < row; j++)
            tab3[i][j] = that.tab[i][j]+tab[i][j];
        return tab3;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example.

Comment: This is not how operator overloading works. See here for some examples: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Why would you make `Operations` inherit from `matrix`? This is *insane*!

Comment: I want to train myself to inherit from a template class.

Comment: You're training on a wrong example.

Comment: @George: --- "Why would you stab yourself?" --- "I wanted to train to cut meat." There is plenty occasion to train yourself to templated inheritance. This is not one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator+()` is normally expected to either be a member of the class it acts on (and accept one argument) or be a non-member that accepts two arguments.

For example;

```
class matrix
{
    public:

        matrix operator+(const matrix &) const;   // member version
};
```

or

```
class matrix
{
    public:

        friend matrix operator+(const matrix &, const matrix &);
};

matrix operator+(const matrix &, const matrix &);
```

Note that friendship is optional in the second case, if the matrix provides public member functions that the `operator+()` needs.

The two approaches cannot be mixed.  If the compiler encounters a class with both forms of `operator+()`, it has no basis to prefer calling one over the other, and will reject code like `c = a+b` due to ambiguity.

It is not also possible for another class (like your `Operations`) to provide a non-static member function `operator+()` that accepts two arguments of type `matrix`.   The error message you are getting about a "non-function" is referring to that (albeit the compiler vendor has used rather cryptic wording for the error message).

Also note that `operator+()` should generally return by value, rather than returning a reference.   Returning a reference usually causes expression like `c = a+b` to work differently than expected - and (depending on what reference is returned) can cause the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: You haven't given any information that would justify one or the other, so either will do. Just not both at once.    You will also need a working assignment operator, copy constructor, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I've just understood what you mean when you say that it is possible to have only one definition of the operator. I choose to implement the member class function but I am getting an error. Code is in edit of the question. Can you please where I am making a mistake with the way I define the member class operator?

Comment: Your `operator+()` needs to return an instance of `matrix`, not a pointer to pointer to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just supposed to overload the + operator for the `matrix` class

```
matrix& operator+(matrix& other){
   ....
}
```

You can therefor use it like :

```
matrix<type> a;
// initialise a
matrix<type> b;
// initialise b
matrix<type> c = a+b; // a+b <=> a.operator+(b);
```

Comment: You think wrong.    `operator+()` should not return a reference, since it makes expressions like `a = a+b` behave differently than the caller might assume.